# DataTableの特定の列に対して重複判定したい

Tags: c#

## 前提

（例）A テーブルがあって、会社コードと部署コードで Distinct をかけたい
Column1, Column2

### Aテーブル

```
(1)001,A
(2)002,A
(3)001,C
(4)003,B
(5)004,D
(6)001,A
(7)002,A
```

```
//DataTableの作成 ※ATableからデータを取得する処理のイメージ
DataTable dt = Aテーブル;

//DataViewの作成
DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;

//Distinctをかける
DataTable resultDt = dv.ToTable(true, "Column1", "Column2");
```

## 結果

```
(1)001,A
(2)002,A
(3)001,C
(4)003,B
(5)004,D
```

---

## 発生している問題

上記の結果はコード上でも確認して理解できたのですが、以下のようにコードを変更したら

```
//Distinctをかける
DataTable resultDt = dv.ToTable(true, , "Column2");
```

出力が以下のようになり Column1 が完全に消えてしまいました。

### Aテーブル

```
(1)A
(3)C
(4)B
(5)D
```

A テーブルで Column2 で重複判定して以下の様に出力させるにはどのように実装すればよいのでしょうか？

### 欲しい出力結果

```
(1)001,A
(3)001,C
(4)003,B
(5)004,D
```

---

## 補足情報 (OS, ツールのバージョンなど)

参考:

- [DataTableに対してDistinctをかける方法 - Road to NAgiler](https://kumat.hatenadiary.org/entry/20080528/p1)

Comment: この [【C#】DataTableをDistinctしたい。](https://teratail.com/questions/15183) の考え方が応用できるのでは？

Comment: `Group by` の話のように見えます。本家にて同じようなことをしてる投稿を見つけました。https://stackoverflow.com/a/19407930/10882610

Comment: kunifさん、wataさんコメントありがとうございました。

Comment: wataさんURL通りにやったら上手く行きました。

Answer (score 1):

`Group by` の話のように見えます。
本家にて同じようなことをしてる投稿を見つけました。[stackoverflow.com/a/19407930/10882610](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19407930/10882610)

Linqで`Group by`するコーディング例：

```
dt = dt.AsEnumerable()
       .GroupBy(r => new {Col1 = r["Col1"], Col2 = r["Col2"]})
       .Select(g => g.OrderBy(r => r["PK"]).First())
       .CopyToDataTable();
```

---

<sup>この投稿は @wata さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/53400/#comment55975_53400)などを元に編集し、[コミュニティWiki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1583)として投稿しました。</sup>